# How to impute based on previous known departure and next known arrival?

Tags: python, list, dynamic, missing-data, imputets

[image: Example]

Basically, I have a list of arrival and departure timings. In the picture below, i = 3 and i = 4 has departure 0. What I am looking to achieve is to take i=2's departure (as my last known), and i=5's departure (as my next known), take the difference (14:44:39 - 14:41:03) and divide it equally across the missing values I have, which is i=3 and i=4. This is not a fixed pattern and it should be dynamic (i.e, sometimes I can have 2, 3 or n number of missing values)

So my question is, how can I dynamically (or recursively) check what is my next known number and divide the differences equally among the missing values that I have?

In this example, the difference between my last known and next known is 216 seconds. Since there are 3 intervals between i=2 to i=3, i=3 to i=4 and i=4 to i=5 my timestamp for my i=3 is 14:42:15 and i=4 is 14:43:27 (72s).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I converted each `Departure` data item into a `timestamps_in_seconds` in order to calculate the linear interpolation between them `timestamps_interpolated` before converting the calculated data into the desired format `departure_interpolated`.

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Convert a timestamp to a formatted date "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
def convert_to_datetime(timestamp):
    date_time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
    formatted_date = date_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return formatted_date

# Create a pandas Series with a mix of timestamps and zeros (inspired from the example provided)
departure_data = pd.Series([
    "2023-10-09 14:36:26",
    "2023-10-09 14:38:03",
    "2023-10-09 14:41:03",
    0,
    0,
    "2023-10-09 14:44:39",
    "2023-10-09 14:45:39",
    "2023-10-09 14:48:39",
    "2023-10-09 14:51:10",
    "2023-10-09 14:54:14",
    "2023-10-09 14:55:28",
    "2023-10-09 14:56:40",
    "2023-10-09 14:57:40",
    "2023-10-09 14:58:31",
    "2023-10-09 15:01:11",
    "2023-10-09 15:02:11",
    "2023-10-09 15:03:11",
    "2023-10-09 15:04:11",
    "2023-10-09 15:05:41",
    "2023-10-09 15:06:59",
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    "2023-10-09 15:08:41"
])

# Replace zeros with None in the data Series
departure_data = departure_data.replace(0, None)

# Convert the data to DateTime objects with the specified format
departure_data = pd.to_datetime(departure_data, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# Convert DateTime objects to seconds since epoch, with None for NaT values
timestamps_in_seconds = departure_data.apply(lambda x: int(x.timestamp()) if x is not pd.NaT else None)

# Create a DataFrame with two columns: 'data' and 'timestamps_in_seconds'
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'departure': departure_data,
    'timestamps_in_seconds': timestamps_in_seconds
})

# Interpolate the 'timestamps_in_seconds' column using linear interpolation
df['timestamps_interpolated'] = df['timestamps_in_seconds'].interpolate(method='linear')

# Calculate the difference in seconds between consecutive timestamps (to a better understanding) -- not necessary
df['diff_timestamps_in_seconds'] = df['timestamps_interpolated'].diff()

# Convert the 'timestamps_interpolated' back to formatted dates
df['departure_interpolated'] = df['timestamps_interpolated'].apply(convert_to_datetime)
```

Here's the output (consider the **departure_interpolated** column):

|  | departure | timestamps_in_seconds | timestamps_interpolated | diff_timestamps_in_seconds | departure_interpolated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-10-09 14:36:26 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | nan | 2023-10-09 14:36:26 |
| 1 | 2023-10-09 14:38:03 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 97 | 2023-10-09 14:38:03 |
| 2 | 2023-10-09 14:41:03 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 180 | 2023-10-09 14:41:03 |
| 3 | NaT | nan | 1.69686e+09 | 72 | 2023-10-09 14:42:15 |
| 4 | NaT | nan | 1.69686e+09 | 72 | 2023-10-09 14:43:27 |
| 5 | 2023-10-09 14:44:39 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 72 | 2023-10-09 14:44:39 |
| 6 | 2023-10-09 14:45:39 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 60 | 2023-10-09 14:45:39 |
| 7 | 2023-10-09 14:48:39 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 180 | 2023-10-09 14:48:39 |
| 8 | 2023-10-09 14:51:10 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 151 | 2023-10-09 14:51:10 |
| 9 | 2023-10-09 14:54:14 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 184 | 2023-10-09 14:54:14 |
| 10 | 2023-10-09 14:55:28 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 74 | 2023-10-09 14:55:28 |
| 11 | 2023-10-09 14:56:40 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 72 | 2023-10-09 14:56:40 |
| 12 | 2023-10-09 14:57:40 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 60 | 2023-10-09 14:57:40 |
| 13 | 2023-10-09 14:58:31 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 51 | 2023-10-09 14:58:31 |
| 14 | 2023-10-09 15:01:11 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 160 | 2023-10-09 15:01:11 |
| 15 | 2023-10-09 15:02:11 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 60 | 2023-10-09 15:02:11 |
| 16 | 2023-10-09 15:03:11 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 60 | 2023-10-09 15:03:11 |
| 17 | 2023-10-09 15:04:11 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 60 | 2023-10-09 15:04:11 |
| 18 | 2023-10-09 15:05:41 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 90 | 2023-10-09 15:05:41 |
| 19 | 2023-10-09 15:06:59 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 78 | 2023-10-09 15:06:59 |
| 20 | NaT | nan | 1.69686e+09 | 20.4 | 2023-10-09 15:07:19 |
| 21 | NaT | nan | 1.69686e+09 | 20.4 | 2023-10-09 15:07:39 |
| 22 | NaT | nan | 1.69686e+09 | 20.4 | 2023-10-09 15:08:00 |
| 23 | NaT | nan | 1.69686e+09 | 20.4 | 2023-10-09 15:08:20 |
| 24 | 2023-10-09 15:08:41 | 1.69686e+09 | 1.69686e+09 | 20.4 | 2023-10-09 15:08:41 |